# Google analytics, set multiple values for an custom metric

Tags: google-analytics

i have a dropdown box, when i select a value in drop down and click submit button, i am assigning tat to a custom metric.The issue is i dont want the value to be reset every time i choose a dropdown, i want it keep adding. 
Expected: many values to a particular date.
LIQUID  23/10/2014
LIQUID  23/10/2014
SOLID   23/10/2014
SOLID   23/10/2014
SOLID   23/10/2014
SOLID   23/10/2014

Wats happening is only last selected value is being set. 
SOLID   23/10/2014

Any idea how can it be done.

Comment: can your show us any code?

Comment: I really doubt that you are assigning "LIQUID 23/10/2014" to a custom metric (metric is numbers or currency, not strings). You probably mean custom dimensions. They are sent once per user interaction, so if you want multiple values per interaction you need to concatenate them clientside and send the complete value with the next user interaction.